# 403 Error on homepage of second language

Tags: craft3, localization, multi-site, language

We are trying to setup a second language. We've gone through the steps and created a second website, we defined the base URL as @web/de for the second language (German).

The deeper sections are working fine (e.g. www.url.com/de/kontakt). However we can't get the second homepage to work on the URL www.url.com/de. We get a 403 access denied from nginx. We followed all the steps in the documentation (https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/localization.html), but can't get it to work. I assume we are missing something or forgot to do something.

The homepage is a single. In sections, we have left the URI blank for both, the default english site as well as the german site. The template is the same for both.

As a dev environment, we are using Local by Flywheel on a local workstation.

Here are some screenshots of our configuration:
[image]

Site overview:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you define the the locale url in your config?

I do it like this:

**.env**

```
SITE_URL_DE="@web"
SITE_URL_EN="@web/en"
SITE_URL_FR="@web/fr"
SITE_URL_IT="@web/it"
```

general.php

```
// Global settings
  '*' => [
    'siteUrl' => [
        'siteDe' => getenv('SITE_URL_DE'),
        'siteFr' => getenv('SITE_URL_FR'),
        'gsiteEn' => getenv('SITE_URL_EN'),
        'siteIt' => getenv('SITE_URL_IT'),
    ],
  ],
```

Then you can use those as your base URL's:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We hadn't set those variables. We have added them, however it still doesn't work. I wonder, we haven't set an index.php in the web/de folder - do we need this? 

I've added some screenshots to show how my configuration looks.

Comment: You don't need to have `web/de` folders any longer in Craft 3

Comment: Hmm. Apart from that it looks the same. I run on apache so my guess it's an ngnix thing.

Comment: Seriously...that was it. We removed the de folder and now everything works fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to hear. The move from a multilanguage site from `craft 2` to `craft 3` isn't that strightforward altough it's much simpler now actually.

Comment: I've actually run into a new problem now... It might be related though so I'll just quickly ask it here but if it's better to create a new question let me know.

When I publish the website everything seems to work, except for the homepage of the second language. Where before I got a 403, and after deleting the web/de folder it worked locally, published the web/de homepage returns a 404. If you have any more suggestion I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Ugh. I would open a new question. Could be that your path's for the template are not in order.